# How to save multiple records in one query with callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activerecord-import

I have an array of new objects of active records I want to save them all in one query and I also want to call before_create callback. I used [activerecored-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem and also tried with insert method these both methods skip the callbacks what is best way to do that?

Comment: Could you please write any code sample here.

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2509320/385532

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you read the [activerecord-import wiki](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki) there are lost of interesting facts on how to use that gem there.

here is a key: you have to `require 'activerecord-import'`

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```

this is how you save 10 records with 1 call

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I want to call my callbacks you can read this https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Callbacks