# is there a way to save multiple records with attachements at once without calling insert each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have some files that I need to save to the database, and every file should be attached to a instance of an `ActiveRecord` like so:

```
pdf_files.each do |pdf_file|
 cipher_file = ...
 payslip = MyhraPayslips::Payslip.new(myhra_users_user_id: user_to_update.id, payslip_date: 
          DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
 payslip.payslip.attach(io: File.open(cipher_file), filename: File.basename(pdf_file), 
         content_type: 'application/pdf')
 payslip.save
end
```

Since I have many files, I want to insert them into the database all at once, and, because I have to call `attach` method on each record, I can't just do it with bulk insert or use `create` instead of `new`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving multiple objects in a single call in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509320/saving-multiple-objects-in-a-single-call-in-rails)

Comment: Well it is actually slower that what i have already, because i have to store the data in some Array which is a loop, and loop a second time to attach each file with the created record which call insert each time.